# Count max rectangles number, that can be placed inside character

Tags: algorithm, fonts, count, char

I need a solution for quite complex problem. Exactly, I need to calculate the number of rectangles that can be placed inside letter/character with given size, considering that all rectangles are the same size, but it(the size) and the letter/character(of some regular specific font) itself can be changed by user(this will be used as webside calculator of signboard price).
If describe this graphically, it looks like this:

[alt text http://habreffect.ru/files/319/aab0644b9/img.png](http://habreffect.ru/files/319/aab0644b9/img.png)

Any ideas or useful links will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sound like bin-packing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem . Do you need an optimal solution? Is there a maximum number of rectangles to be placed inside an area? If so, how many rectangles?

Comment: Does it need to be precise or approximate?

Comment: @Bart K Thanks for the tip, I'll look into it today - and let you know if I come to the right solution. Though the only problem I see here is the indefinite form of the characters in font.
P.S. Yes, it has to be close to optimal. And there's no actual limitations by quantity as really the rectangles are lightning elements placed into title(company name) of signboard.

@Marcelo Cantos It doesn't need to be absolutely ideal, but it has to be at least close to real production number of rectangles(i.e. lightning elements).

Answer (score 1):

This is 2D bin-packing. This page might clear it up a bit: http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/C.L.Mumford/heidi/Background.html

The wiki page on bin-packing: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem has a link to a software package which might come in handy: http://code.google.com/p/caparf/

You are unlucky that this is NP-Hard. You are lucky that this is a widely researched topic and has many approximation algorithms. Most current literature on bin-packing should have some information which should help.

Comment: Thanks. But the next problem is that I cannot figure out how to calculate the area of the character or its line length.

Comment: @Nickolay: You probably should create a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

About size of characters:

Print char in bitmap and count black regons